# Why are covectors defined through the dual space

Tags: tensors

When defining covectors (also known as 1-forms or as dual vectors), we define them as linear scalar maps.

It is clear that linear scalar maps can take various forms. My question is: why do we define this map to be such that it satisfies the idea of duality?

Is there a deeper notion/topic in differential geometry (or similar) where the idea of defining this map as satisfying the duality conditions is relevant?

Why then is the definition so open? See, for instance, Tensors made easy by Bernacchi (page 9, see screenshot below) or [this set of notes](https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2016/other/mla/ma.pdf), page 23.

[image: From Bernacchi's book, page 9]

Comment: What do you mean by "so open"? As in relaxed or weak? Being linear and returning only scalars imposes a restriction. For example, there is pretty large (in the sense of dimension) of the domain that will need to be sent to zero.

Comment: I mean that it is not precise. Meaning that a linear scalar map can take different definitions, but we then learn that we are interested in a linear scalar map that then defines the dual space. Why do we want this to be the linear scalar map?

Comment: It is not "**a** linear scalar map that then defines the dual space". It is *all* linear scalar maps, what constitutes the (linear) dual.

Comment: That helps. I see. The idea of defining the set of scalar linear maps and then showing that the so-called coordinate forms form a basis ties it up. Thanks!